# How to call a method from another class?

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

```
public class ClassOut {

    abstract class ClassIn {

        int x = 20;

        public void print() {
            System.out.println("value = " + getX());
        }

        public abstract int getX();
    }
}
```

How to call method `print()` from another class ?

Answer (score 1):

If the abstract was a standalone class (not inner) then you could simply extend it

```
public class MineClass extends Classin {

   // implement getX
}
```

then you can call it as

```
new MineClass().print();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. As you have an abstract class you'll need a concrete class to extends it, doing that you can `@override` the method `print()` in your subclass, for example:

```
class ClassInChild extends ClassIn {
    @override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("new value = " + getX());
    }

    // mandatory because it is abstract
    @override
    public int getX() {
        return 5;
    }
 }

 ClassIn classIn = new ClassInChild();
 classIn.print();
```

If it all goes right, you should receive `new value = 5` as response.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiation of abstract class is not possible you have to subclass it in order to use its non static fields and methods.

```
new ClassOut().new ClassIn(){
    public int getX() {
         return 1; 
    }
}.print();
```

Here I've done the anonymous implementation​ of the inner abstract class in order to create the instance of it and call the instance method.